# Display only 20 characters from content? Display paragraphs?

Tags: php, mysql

I have separate question really which I need help. I only want to display say 20 characters from 'content'.

```
    <?php
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q'] !== ' ') {
        $searchq = $_GET['q'];

        $q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM article WHERE title LIKE '%$searchq%' OR content LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die(mysqli_error());
        $c = mysqli_num_rows($q);
        if($c == 0) {
            $output = 'No search results for <strong>"' .   $searchq    .   '"</strong>';
        } else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row ['title'];
                $content = $row ['content'];
            $output .= '<a href="article.php?id=' .$id. '">

                <h3>'.$title.'</h3></a>'.$content.'';
            }
        }
    } else {
            header("location: ./");
    }
    print("$output");
    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Separate questions should be asked separately.

Comment: please note: your code is open to sql-injection hacking. Use "$searchq = mysqli_escape_string($_GET['q']);"

Answer (score 0):

i will answer your first question:

insert this line after:

```
$content = $row ['content'];
if(strlen($content)>20) $content=substr ($content,0,19);
```